# How to clear memory usage of UICollectionView (consist of UICollectionViewCell (with UIImageView)) when ViewDidDisappear is called in swift

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a **UICollectionView** consists of **UICollectionViewCell** of 60+ cells and an **UIImageView** in each cell. I want to clear the memory usage of this UIViewController when going to another UIViewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just reload it with 0 number of cells and go to another view

Comment: mycollectionView.reloadData() like this? How to reload collectionView with 0 number of cells?.

Comment: like you can make number of items to zero while disappearing and reload it